# Raspberry OS lite, TFT display, Openbox : Cannot init x

Tags: x11, x-server, openbox

I just installed Raspberry OS lite (no desktop environment), plugged a WaveShare 2.8 TFT display in and installed Openbox and the tools below:

`xorg openbox obmenu openbox-menu menu slim` (slim for auto login)

And lastly I ran shell script `./LCD28-show lite` which you can see [here](https://github.com/waveshare/LCD-show/blob/master/LCD28-show): .
This setup worked with all systems by far, this time I am getting an error as follows:

```
Server terminated with error (1)
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

When I start openbox I get this error message:
`Openbox-Message: Failed to open the display from the DISPLAY environment variable`

Please let me know if there is any particular error log that could be useful and i will provide it.